# How to create menu links from array of objects

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects that I want to use for side navigation. It works okay except for the items which have more than one sub item.

```
  const menuItems = [
    {
      id: 1000,
      name: "Dashboard",
      content: ["dashboard"],
      icon: <GoDashboard />,
      link: "dashboard",
    },
    {
      id: 1001,
      name: "Contact Form",
      content: ["entries"],
      icon: <RiContactsLine />,
      link: "contact-enquiries",
    },
    {
      id: 1002,
      name: "Courses",
      content: ["Add course", "All courses"],
      icon: <HiOutlineDesktopComputer />,
      link: ["add-course", "courses"],
    },
  ];
```

I have tried to cut out a lot of unnecessary code in the below like logic for classes etc. but the problem is with the `<Link>`. It displays the items correctly but each item has the same link ie: both item's links. So, "Add course" instead of being `'add-course'` is `'add-course,courses'`

```
<ul className={styles.navList}>
  {menuItems.map((v) => (
    <li
      key={v.id}
    >
      {sideActive === v.id && (
        <ul>
          {v.content.map((val, index) => (
            <Link to={`/admin/${v.link}`} key={index}>
              <li className={styles.subList__item}>{val}</li>
            </Link>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </li>
  ))}
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the best way but I actually got it to work using an array of objects instead of an array.

```
  content: [
    { title: "Add course", url: "add-course" },
    { title: "All courses", url: "all-courses" },
  ],
```

And then in the loop I accessed them like `val.title` and `val.url`